# Nav. bar hovering color

Tags: html, css

Background color (red) misses out after I  am hovering drop down items.

What should I do to keep the background color of the menu item I am in?

```
<style>

    nav ul 
    {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:grey;
    }

    nav ul li 
    {
    display:inline-block;
    }

    nav ul a 
    {
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
    }

    nav ul a:hover 
    {
    background:red;
    }

    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
    }

        nav ul li:hover ul{
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
    }

        nav ul ul li
        {
        display:block;
        border-bottom:solid 1px black;
        }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">three</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ay</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">bee</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the parent `li` is not attracting the `:hover`, so a hover on the child submenu doesn't keep it active. As such, you need to move the style change to the `li:hover` instead of the `a` child, as the submenu is an sibling of the `a` and not direct child.

Change:

```
nav ul a:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

To:

```
nav ul li:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p8t9qo9v/)

Comment: what about nav ul li a:hover

Comment: @SajadLfc `nav ul li a:hover ` wouldnt resolve the underlying issue that the child `a` loses the hover event

Comment: re: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p8t9qo9v/2/ item 3 on the menu vs the fiddle in the answer

Comment: it is the same in your answer too,both fiddles ouput the same

Comment: @SajadLfc, fiddle two looks cleaner. It hovers only either main menu or one of the sub menu.